# How to access request headers in onHeadersReceived event in Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, http-headers

I was doing something similar:

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders.addListener(function (details) {

    for (var i = 0; i < details.requestHeaders.length; ++i)
    {
        if (details.requestHeaders[i].name.toLowerCase() === 'user-agent')
        {
            message.useragent = details.requestHeaders[i].value;
        } 
        else if (details.requestHeaders[i].name.toLowerCase() === 'referer')
        {
            message.referrer = details.requestHeaders[i].value;
        } 
        else if (details.requestHeaders[i].name.toLowerCase() === 'cookie')
        {
            message.cookies = details.requestHeaders[i].value;
            console.log(details.requestHeaders[i].value);
        }
    }
    return {
        requestHeaders: details.requestHeaders
    };
}, {
    urls: [
        '<all_urls>'
    ],
    types: [
        'main_frame',
        'sub_frame',
        'xmlhttprequest'
    ]
}, [
    'blocking',
    'requestHeaders'
]);

and on receiving response:

chrome.webRequest.onHeadersReceived.addListener(function (details) {

    message.url = details.url;
    // and some other details
    ...
```

But recently I discovered that sometimes request parameters stored and response parameters stored belong to different request response pairs. So, is this possible to access request headers in onHeadersReceived event to prevent mismatch.

Comment: Side note: Since you're not modifying the request headers at all, I suggest to not use `blocking` in your webRequest event. Blocking events slow down network requests.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `requestId` field to match headers saved in `onBeforeSendHeaders` with those in `onHeadersReceived`.

> Request IDs are unique within a browser session. As a result, they could be used to relate different events of the same request.

Comment: that would require storing of multiple requests. Can't we reference request header using request id in onHeaderReceived

Comment: @adnankamili there is no built-in mechanism for that.